# three.js - Unable to render THREE.Line when using WebGLDeferredRenderer

Tags: three.js, webgl

I've recently converted my scene to using a `WebGLDeferredRenderer` as it's easier for me to implement SSAO. However, since converting to the deferred renderer I'm unable to render `THREE.Line` objects. Instead, I get the following error:

```
THREE.Material: 'shading' parameter is undefined.
```

This is the code for the lines (a grid) that works fine when I'm not using a deferred renderer:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -2500, 0, 0 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 2500, 0, 0 ) );

linesMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0xb9b9b9, linewidth: 0.1} );

for ( var i = 0; i <= 50; i ++ ) {

    var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, linesMaterial );
    line.position.z = ( i * 100 ) - 2500;
    scene.add( line );

    var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, linesMaterial );
    line.position.x = ( i * 100 ) - 2500;
    line.rotation.y = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
    scene.add( line );

}
```

I've tried adding a `shading` property to the `THREE.LineBasicMaterial` with a value such as `THREE.FlatShading` but I still get the same error.

The error is being reported from the `THREE.Material` section of the main three.js script. If it helps, I'm using a slightly customised version of three.js – http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/js/three.max.deferredday.js

Any and all help is appreciated!

**Update**

[Here is a quick hack](http://mrdoob.com/projects/htmleditor/#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) with the public version of Three.js exhibiting this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because lines and `LineBasicMaterial` are not supported (yet) with WebGLDeferredRenderer.

As a work-around, you can do this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 5000, 5000, 50, 50 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xb9b9b9, wireframe: true } );
scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) );
```

Unfortunately `material.wireframeLinewidth` is not supported either.

three.js r.55